# More curiousity on what is considered "on topic", as a question at the top of the site seems completely unfit but has a plethora of upvotes

Tags: discussion

This question from April [How to work on my personal ideas during the weekend](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-to-work-on-my-personal-ideas-during-the-weekend) seems the antithesis of what this site is about.  It's about spending your personal time on the weekends outside of work.

I am in the dark as to how this has been deemed acceptable.  From the FAQ:

```
You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. 

The Workplace - Stack Exchange is for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting.
```

I don't want to stir the pot, I'm just curious how this is an acceptable question.

Comment: You shouldn't feel bad about bringing up a legitimate question about a post on the site, as long as you bring it up in a constructive manner, which you've done a great job of. +1  You're trying to make the site better, and that's great! ;)

Comment: I agree with @jmort253, but just be careful. I wanted to improve this site so much that I got banned (for seven days) because I disagreed with the current crop of moderators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All I can really say is that that post was from the private beta of the site when things were very different and we were sorting out what's on/off topic. A lot of more discussiony topics flourished in that brief period, and trying to retroactively moderate them isn't very pleasant nor is it all that productive. That question was actually asked on the *very first day in private beta*.

If people want to close posts like that I'd encourage them to vote, but as a moderator I don't feel comfortable going back and closing swaths of questions because they were asked in the site's defining period.

The birth of the site was a bit rough, as it always is. We had a lot of very constructive discussions and I think we've solidified our policies and expectations very well. But when that happened there were a lot of things we missed. If those posts get flags and close votes, sure, let's close them. But I don't think it's constructive to start looking at the very first posts on the site and start asking "why can't I ask this *now*". We tried to [stop the quality problem early.](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/is-workplace-going-to-follow-the-same-life-cycle-as-other-se-sites-for-subjectiv/147#147) I think we did very well, but it's hard to have a concrete policy **from the very first day of the site.**

---

The mentioned post got 3 community close votes so I went and slapped a Closed ribbon on it.

Comment: Heh, our first broken window...